# Can I link mismatched parts with jumper wires?

Tags: connector, wiring, automotive, adapter, jumper

I'm out of my element here and I don't know much about electrical engineering so please excuse the bad terminology. A light on my car stopped working and it's a long story but the easiest way to fix it is to retrofit a newer light to the old connector. The female adaptor of the old part is square while the new part is supposed to take a round adaptor. I wanted to know if I can connect the two parts with jumper wires rather than doing what others have done like shave the sides of the original adaptor or trying to solder the exposed terminals inside the round socket.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Seal everything up when done so no water gets in there to short things out.